# Shell script - not using if loop

Tags: shell, if-statement

I have an if loop that tells it if it gets a certain argument to do an install, however if it doesn't receive that argument, it should quit... am I doing something wrong? No matter the argument, it does the install.

```
echo "You ran the command: $1"
if [ $0=zero ]
then
  echo "Zero Install"
else
  echo "Sorry, wrong argument."
  exit
fi
if [ $1=install ]
then
  if [ $2=brew ]
  then
    /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
  else
    echo "Sorry, invalid package."
    exit
  fi
else
  echo "Sorry, invalid command."
  exit
fi
```

Comment: check you scripts with http://shellcheck.net

Comment: An _if loop_ ???? That doesn't exist

Comment: Are you confused about parameters - $1, $2, $3, etc are the args.  $0 is the program. $0 could quite possibly include a path (if that was how the script was excuted).  AND when you use the variables what if the value passed has a space in it ?? "$0", etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I figured it out. You have to put ""s around the $1 or $2 etc. Also spaces around the if operator (=). Thanks to KamilCuk for suggesting shellcheck.net, that worked!